# Why does html5 video tag does not work in Firefox even if I'm using the right format?

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I was trying to add a video to my web page with  tag, but the tag doesn't work correctly. Here is the code:

```
<video src="/static/videos/test1.webm" type="video/webm" controls></video>
```

In the web-player I get "No video with supported format and MIME type found" error. In the Internet some people say that it is the server problem and the main problem is in .htaccess server file. But I'm using Django default web-server and there is no such file here. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you obtain the file from this URL? Why don't you use `{% static 'videos/test1.webm %}`?

Comment: I use the static tag, but it doesn't help - I still get the same error

Comment: But can you *fetch* the page (by putting the URL in the URL bar of the browser)?

Comment: No, I get the TemplateNotFoundError(My URL was 127.0.0.1/static/videos/test1.webm if I understand you correctly)

Comment: Then I have the idea that you did not implement `staticfiles` correctly: it looks like you defined a custom view for it, and that it does not return a webm stream, but aims to return a rendered HTML file.

Comment: Yes, you are right - my view function for this page only return HTML render, but do I need to point that there will be some static objects in my HTML in this view function?

Comment: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

Comment: Okey, thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

**For a quick fix-- just focus on the part in bold. For details you may read the entire thing.**

Error is probably in your static files path. Above src should work if you have your test1.webm video in directory structure as follows:

```
project/app_name/static/app_name/test1.webm  # when app_name= videos
```

But this should have worked default. So I think you have created a new static folder directly in your project (outside all apps) with following directory structure:

```
project/static/videos/test1.webm
```

**To make this work put following code in your `project/project/settings.py`**

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [  #for static assets that aren’t tied to a particular app
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
]
```

To take it a step further if you have tried to deploy your django website, you may have moved `settings.py` to another settings directory and renamed it `base.py` file:  `project/project/settings/base.py`

In that case change your BASE_DIR in new base.py file to :

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```